# React Native component not refreshing on state update

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm having trouble understanding why my component isn't updating after I update my state:

```
const LinuxQuiz = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [questionDone, setQuestionDone] = React.useState(false);
  const [answersDone, setAnswersDone] = React.useState({
    A: false,
    B: false,
    C: false,
    D: false,
  });
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
        <TypeWriter
          text={linuxData[index].question}
          delay={5}
          setQuestionDone={setQuestionDone}
          setAnswersDone={setAnswersDone}
          letter="Z"
          answersDone={answersDone}
        />
      </View>
      {linuxData[index].answers.map((answer, index) => {
        if (questionDone) {
          const letter = alphabet[index];
          const values = Object.values(answersDone);
          if (index === 0) {
            return (
              <TypeWriter
                text={`${alphabet[index]}. ${answer}\n`}
                delay={5}
                answer
                setQuestionDone={setQuestionDone}
                setAnswersDone={setAnswersDone}
                letter={alphabet[index]}
                answersDone={answersDone}
              />
            );
          } else if (values[index - 1] === true) {
            return (
              <TypeWriter
                text={`${alphabet[index]}. ${answer}\n`}
                delay={5}
                answer
                setQuestionDone={setQuestionDone}
                setAnswersDone={setAnswersDone}
                letter={alphabet[index]}
                answersDone={answersDone}
              />
            );
          }
        }
      })}
      <Button onPress={() => setIndex((index) => index + 1)}>Check</Button>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LinuxQuiz;
```

The index is changing but the component isn't refreshing and so the next data object in the array is just being concatenated to the Text on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render a list of objects, you must use the key property so React knows what to rerender and when.

```
//... map function
//..
            return (
              <TypeWriter
                key={myUniqueKey}
                text={`${alphabet[index]}. ${answer}\n`}
                delay={5}
                answer
                setQuestionDone={setQuestionDone}
                setAnswersDone={setAnswersDone}
                letter={alphabet[index]}
                answersDone={answersDone}
              />
    )
```

Currently, your key is set to an index of the mapped item. If you update the order or data inside the list, react still thinks that elements should stay the same and no update is dispatched, since the key of all elements are the same as keys of previous elements.

key should be unique to every item you are rendering.

Comment: This did the trick, completely forgot the keys!